# Finding the minimum of a nested list that has a constant in element[1]

Tags: python, list, min

I have a nested list:

```
freqList = [[4, 2], [3, 2], [1, 1]]
```

**And I want to find the minimum number in index[0] that has a constant (value) of 2 in index[1].**

For this list elements 1 and 2 have a value of 2 at index[1] within the nested list therefore the 4 and 3 fit the criteria and the min number is 3 so the output should be **3**

```
    for val in freqList:
        print(val[0])
```

Gives me the values in index[0] of the list but I'm not sure how to only print the values of index[0] that have a value of 2 in index[1] and then how to select the minimum.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I want to be sure, you want to get minimum of the first elements in the lists which second elements is `2`  inside the nested list, am I right?

Comment: yes you are correct, thank you for your help

Comment: Hey @Cedee If my or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get minimum of the first elements in the inner lists:

```py
min([val[0] for val in freqList])
```

Also if you want to check inner lists for conditions:

```py
min([val[0] for val in freqList if CONDITION)
```

which if your condition is `val[1] == 2` (Also your question's answer)

```py
min([val[0] for val in freqList if val[1] == 2])
```

or even you can check for multiple condition:

```py
min([val[0] for val in freqList if ((val[1] == 2) and (len(val) == 2))])
```

Comment: Checking for multiple conditions is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in Python so my solution can be too complicated.

I can suggest the following approach

```
lst2 = []
for sublist in lst:
    if len( sublist ) >= 2 and sublist[1] == 2:
        lst2.append( sublist[0] )
min_value = min( lst2 )
```

where `lst` is you original list of lists.

Using the built list `lst2` you can output all values at index 0 of sub-lists that have at index 1 a value equal to 2.

For example

```
for value in lst2:
    print( value, end = ' ' )
print()
print( min( lst2 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define function like this:

```py
def find_minimum(where, const_id, const_val):
    values = []

    for i in where:
        if i[const_id] == const_val:
            values.append(i[0])

    return min(values)
```

Usage:

```py
list = [[4, 2], [3, 2], [1, 1]]
minimum = find_minimum(list, 1, 2)
print(minimum)
```